# how to use PHP in JavaScript code snippet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**I want to use PHP inside the JavaScript code snippet.
 Instead .......... in the following code snippet.
How can I do this?**

```
<td>
    @foreach(\App\Asset::where('group_id', $AssetGroup->id)->get() as $asset)
        {{ $asset->name ?: '' }}
        <?php echo '<br>'; ?>
    @endforeach
</td>
<td>
    @if (count(App\Asset::where('group_id', $AssetGroup->id)->get()) !== 0)
        <form action="{{ route('scan') }}">
            <button name="group_id" class="btn btn-warning btn-detail open_modal" style="color: white;"  value="{{ $AssetGroup->id }}"> پویش </button>
        </form>
    @endif
</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var assetgroup = '<tr><td>' + .......... + '</td><td>' + .......... + '</td>';
```

Comment: `var assetgroup = '<tr><td>' + '{{ data.name }}' + '<tr><td>'`?

Comment: @nice_dev question updated

Comment: It's unclear now. Where do you want to use PHP inside JS?

Comment: _Side note:_ You can replace `<?php echo '<br>'; ?>` to just `<br>`. No need to involve PHP there. I would also recommend against making requests to the database directly from the views. Do that in either your controller or services (depending on your setup) and just pass the result to the view. Views should only contain presentation logic.

Comment: @nice_dev yes..

Answer (score 0):

For javascript snippet within `<script>` tags in a blade file

```
//$data is an object while $data2 is an array available in the blade view file
var assetgroup = '<tr><td>' + '{{ $data->val }}' + '</td><td>' + '{{ $data2['val'] }}' + '</td>';
```

To create and assign values to a global variable on `window` object

```html
<script>
    window.App = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        'signedIn'  => auth()->check(),
        'user' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->toJsonVariable() : null,
        'baseUrl'=> config('app.url'),
        ]) !!};
</script>
```